# Sub queries and not having to re-use code

Tags: sql

I have a relatively simple task that is becoming a bit of a minefield because of the way I am currently approaching it, and i am wondering if there is a neater/cleaner way without having so much repeatable code.

Take the case where I am doing the following select:

```
select a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, a.col4, a.col5 from a
```

but `a.col2` and `b.col3` are results of selects themselves, i.e. the above code becomes:

```
select a.col1,
        a.col2 = (select something from somewhere where a.id = b.id),
        a.col3 = (select something_else from somewhere_else where a.id = c.id)
from a
```

then ontop of that, `col4` is the result of a  `CASE`  statement using `col2` and `col3`, and `col5` is another  `CASE`  statement that uses `col4`, `col3`, and `col2`, then suddenly you have something very messy and very repeated:

```
       select a.col1,
            a.col2 = (select something from somewhere where a.id = b.id),
            a.col3 = (select something_else from somewhere_else where a.id = c.id),
            a.col4 = (
                      case
                         when (select something from somewhere where a.id = b.id) = 'X' then 'Y'
                         else 'Z'
                      end
            ),
            a.col5 = [INSERT ALL OF COL4 CODE HERE] = 'Something' THEN
                     (
                      case
                         when (select something_else_again from somewhere_else where a.id = b.id) = 'X' then 'Y'
                         else 'Z'
                      end
                      )
```

This is a real life problem that I am currently in that I have tried to simplify above for question purposes. Surely there is a neater way that I am missing?

Comment: are all the somewhere the same table?

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: It seems col4 and col5 will have the same result. Can you expand the `INSERT ALL OF ALL COL4 CODE HERE` to show how it's different?

Comment: Without some sample data and desired output, it's hard to see what exactly you're trying to achieve and how it could have been done differently. What database are you using?

Comment: I think there might be an error with the col5 in your presentation. col4 can only be Y or Z, so col5 will go directly to Z.

Comment: I've updated the question once again. Hopefully now shows my point especially for Col 5, that its two nested case statements, one of which is just a reptition of col4's CASE statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the database, you can do any of the following. The first two essentially create a new "result table" from which you can select and thus reuse the results of the earlier calculation. The last option is simply normal programming by the use of functions.

Also, both option 1 and 2 would give you the opportunity to join in further tables, which in many cases would be preferred to the sub select you are doing within the select clause

**Option 1: `with` clause**

This works in PostgreSQL, not sure that it works in other databases:

```sql
with result1 as (
   select  [calculation] col1,
           [calculation] col2,
           *
   from    a
),
result2 as (
   select  [calculation] col3,
           *
   from    result1
)
select     [calculation] col4,
           *
from       result2
```

**Option 2: Subqueries**

Should work in all databases.

```
select     [calculation] col4,
           *
from       (
           select  [calculation] col3,
                   *
           from    (
                   select  [calculation] col1,
                           [calculation] col2,
                           *
                   from    a
                   ) tt
           ) t
```

**Option 3: Functions/Procedures**

This depends a bit on the database implementation, you would have to read up on that. But depending on if you want to reuse the logic across multiple queries that might be a good option. On the downside having a select in a function can bring a hidden cost.

It could be something like this though:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calcualtion1(id integer) RETURNS boolean AS $$
BEGIN
   RETURN [do calculation here];
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calcualtion2(id integer) RETURNS boolean AS $$
BEGIN
   RETURN [call calculation1 from here];
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

[...]

select  calculation1(id) col1,
        calculation2(id) col2,
        calculation3(id) col3,
        calculation4(id) col4,
from    a
```

The more I think of it though, I am pretty sure in your case this will have a lot of disadvantages in terms of speed. But noting it here in case anybody else with a similar problem comes along where this is helpful.

Comment: Is it possible for one with to contain the name of another with? For example WITH result1 as (some_code_here), result2 as (somecode here where result1.field = x)?

Comment: Only if you join the result of the earlier `with`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you just need to left outer join `a` and `something` to build the desired select clause.

```
select
  a.col1, 
  b.something as col2,
  b.something_else as col3,
  case a.something when 'X' then 'Y' else 'Z' end as col4,
  case b.something_else_again when 'X' then 'Y' else 'Z' end as col5 
from somewhere a
left outer join somewhere_else b on b.id = a.id
```